Trouble with ASP.NET MVC web app Localization in plugin views
I have an ASP.NET MVC web app which uses IViewLocalizer to localize the pages into different languages.
The directories are organised to in the solution I have Plugins and WebApp among others, and WebApp has all the views, controllers and others. Some of the plugins in Plugins, have a .cshtml view that is used in the web app pages with text that'll appear that I want localized.
When I try to use @Localize['xxx'] like in the other pages, it doesn't work and I get an error

Type or namespace name IViewLocalizer could not be found

How do I fix this?

Could you pls provide necessary code snippets and screenshot for reproducing the issue in my side so that I could troubleshoot it?
